# gcloud auth login fails with an unknown error

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I deleted some folder on my pc by mistake.

Now I have to reauthenticate to gcloud but when I run `gcloud auth login`, it fails with an unknown error.

I am stuck and I don't know what to try

Comment: Start by rebooting. Then reinstall the SDK.

Comment: I am not using windows. But I tried anyway. It's the same

Comment: 1) Windows does not make a difference. Rebooting makes sure that your system will at least let you login. If there were any system problems caused by deleting an unspecified folder, you would be able to check the logs, etc. 2) Turn on debugging and repeat the auth login. Post the details.